# python beautifulsoup4でローカルにあるhtmlファイルの中の入力フォーム操作によって変動する結果を取得できますか？

Tags: python3, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

ある作業で自動的に生成されるindex.htmlと付随するデータがあります。

index.htmlをPCのローカルフォルダ上から起動してブラウザに表示し、画面に表示される入力フォーム部分に検索条件の値を入力し、検索ボタンを押すと画面に表示されているリストが条件に一致するモノのみに絞り込まれる仕組みのあるhtmlとなっています。

このhtmlをbeautifulsoupを使ってローカルindex.htmlを起動し、入力フォーム部分・検索ボタン部分を自動操作しつつ、結果画面の表示内容についてスクレイピングを行いたいのですが、beautifulsoupでこのような作業は可能でしょうか。

python初心者なのでできそうなら調べてやってみようと思います。

Comment: BeautifulSoup はあくまで「HTML を解析する」ツールなので、自動操作が必要な場合 別途 Selenium 等を使わないと実現できないと思います。参考: [SeleniumとBeautifulSoupの違いを簡単にまとめてみた](https://zenn.dev/moimoi_prog/articles/30f9e29569d31b)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。なるほどSeleniumと違いがあるのは知りませんでした。仰るように絞り込み処理部分がjavascript構造なのでSelenium経由でできないか試してみます。

Comment: 自動操作と言っても、フォームに内容を送りながら操作する程度ならrequestsでもできますけどね。javascriptが必要になったらseleniumが必要かもしれません。pyppeteerも便利です。

Answer (score 1):

対処方法【予定】
Seleniumで条件入力し、結果画面のスクレイピングを行う。

cubick様のコメントがほぼほしい答えそのものなのでこれで閉めます。

Comment: コメントで解決したとしても自己解決であっても、ほかの人のためにその回答の中身を記述してください。

Comment: まだ具体的な用意ができないので上記のような記述しかできません。申し訳ありません。